# How to access mails from Gmail using imap

Tags: php, email, ssl, gmail, imap

I was fetching mails from Gmail using Imap, which was working fine. But suddenly it stopped working.
Code is throwing following error
`imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX`

1. I have enabled the Imap Access from Forwarding and POP/IMAP in gmail account.
2. I am using this code

   ```
    $imapPath = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';       $inbox = imap_open($imapPath,env('NDR_EMAIL'),env('NDR_PASSWORD')) or 
           die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
   ```
3. Same thing is working on my Personal gmail account in which I have **Turned On** access to less secure apps.
4. But its not working on my companies account. I could not find option for **Turning On** access to less secure app.

Comment: Login to your company gmail account goto this link https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

Comment: @SaadSuri I don`t have access to company`s main domain account and  the account which I am using for accessing emails don`t have option for less secure app option. So is there any other way of doing the same?